# R - Plotly converts NA label from ggplot2 graphic with a null label

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly, na

It seems that `plotly` converts NA values from `ggplot2` graphic with a null label. Here is a simple example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

col1 <- c("a","c","b","c",NA,"a","b","b",NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(col1)

MyPlot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df$col1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")

print(MyPlot)

ggplotly(MyPlot)
```

[image: MyPlot]

Is there a function to override this behavior and keep the NA label ? Maybe with `plotly_bluid` function who allow changes to the plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could relabel your ticks by using:

```
ggplotly(MyPlot) %>% layout(xaxis = list(ticktext = c("a", "b", "c", "na")))
```